# Courses for non-IT people to study testing?

Tags: training, certification, istqb

I am a non-IT student, but I want to enter into the IT world. Which courses do I have to study to get job in testing? What is the difference between QA tester and ISTQB tester? Which is the best ones?

Comment: Has ISTQB started marketing term "ISTQB Tester" now?

Comment: I would have modified this question to be nicer and more useful, and, but these are not really questions that can be answered without context here. Try contacting some local testing association if there is one to get ideas. Or read some testing books or online material to get better understanding of testing field.

Comment: Those tags are really confusing and have no confirmation in the question wording.

Answer (score 12):

Welcome to SQA, Rosa.  I am not sure your question makes sense; QA is an abbreviation for "Quality Assurance", and often is used as a synonym for testing.  ISTQB is a type of certification for testers.

See also [Do ISTQB/ISEB Testing Certificates prove that someone can test?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/1055/do-istqb-iseb-testing-certificates-prove-someone-can-test) and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caps_lock.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are currently a University student? Have you checked in with your advisors and/or the placement office at your school? I wonder what kind of advice schools are offering these days, and if they are capable of guiding you...

Have you considered transferring into an IT program? That's very often a good way of gaining a useful background that could lead to a testing career. A degree in CS or an IT-related program is one of the things that I look for in a resume.

Answer (score 1):

You can start from reading the 'Software Testing' book written by Ron Patton.
Then you can test something, that you use frequently (for example, an email client etc).
Then you can practice on the uTest.com and earn some money (definetly, you won't make a fortune, but you'll gain rich experience).

Have a nice start ))