# I would like to switch from software development to testing

Tags: automated-testing, selenium2, manual-testing

I am working as a java senior software developer.
I would like to switch my career from programming to testing. Usually I do manual testing in our projects.
I have java exp so I can easily learn selenium tool right?

How hard it will be to switch the career? 
What concepts should I focus more on manual testing?

As a women I have to manage my job and family as well with less pressure on work.

Please suggest me.

Comment: Just curious did you switch roles? And how was the road and life balance?

Answer (score 2):

It actually depends. At first, testing requires other skills than programming. If you will became test engineer with programming experience you would be able to automate more efficient and find accidental regressions better.

> less pressure on work.

and again, softare testing could be very responsible job and you can get much pressure.

> i have java exp

You can became automation tester of web and mobile apps for example. But you should be familiar with testing terminology and basic knowledges about software testing.

Comment: you're welcome and good luck

Answer (score 2):

I think you should first decide:  Manual or Automated testing ?

If you decide automated then you will be programming.  You'll need concepts and practices to manage data and algorithms.  So more programming.  Decide if that's what you want to continue doing.  One huge advantage - it's quite well paid, as much as twice as muich as manual testing.

If you decide Manual that is a different path.  You will want to learn a lot about testing, the various types and levels, boundary values, devices, browsers and versions.  The 'amount' of information and time and resources you will spend will be enormous.  Any field that you specialize in will require this.  Be aware that manual testing is typically less well paid.  Determine if this is ok for you and your family.

My path lately with all these conversation has been a little different as I focus on value:

- Current Value - how am I adding value to the company's bottom line by the bugs I am finding?
- Potential Value - how much value *can I add* by testing and finding bugs before customers do
- Repeated Value - how much value will I add from automated tests reducing manual testing

Answer (score 1):

You can switch your career from java developer to testing field. Mainly software testing includes :

- Manual testing
- Automation testing

At first, you should learn what is software testing.

**What is software testing:**

1. Test plan, test cases, test scenarios creation
2. Test design techniques
3. Bug reports using tool like mantis , BT tracker , Jira
4. Software testing models
5. Software test life cycle

Also if you do preparation of **ISTQB** foundation level exam then you will get perfect and depth knowledge about manual testing things. Reference link : http://www.istqb.org/downloads/finish/16/15.html

If you are excellent in java then it will be easy for you to learn and do work with selenium web driver for functionality testing.

You can also learn [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) automation tool for load testing.

My advice is that do not be in hurry to get work in automation tools , first work as manual tester and understand all things practically that how testing works. then you will enjoy automation easily. Your base of software testing must be clear before automation.

Comment: I know writing Basic test cases.As per your suggestions i am starting my preparation on manual testing first.you suggestion is really helpful.Please tell me the topics which i should concentrate for interview point of view.Thanks.

Comment: @latha - For interview as beginner QA mostly you should be prepare with all important definition related to software testing , basic test case + scenario creation , bug reporting skill etc.

Answer (score 0):

Any time someone considers a career change it can be difficult and stressful as you go from an area of comfort to an area of relative unknowns. The difficult thing with learning about testing is there are so many people out there with misconceptions about what we do that it can be hard for someone new to get and stay on the "right path". I'd suggest finding a mentor (someone with lots of experience) to help reduce the possible stress involved.

I'd also recommend following blogs of testers, reading a few books and trying to get a handle on **what software testing is** before moving on. Searching this site can reveal a few good blogs, books, etc.

My favorite **definition** of software testing is "a technical investigation designed to reveal information about a product or service under test." This means software testers are technical investigators and in order for us to be successful we need to *understand software, modeling systems and how to investigate software using different test techniques*.

Software testing encompasses a lot of things besides the tools and documentation Helping Hands listed.

Also a few other people on this site have asked similar questions, so I invite you to check them out:

- [What developer skills would translate well into doing QA?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/1772/going-from-development-into-qa)
- [Software Testing as a career path? Becoming a test architect](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/5652/software-testing-as-a-career-path-becoming-a-test-architect).

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Every employees other than a TESTER believes like testing is an easy job to do, and it consist of less work pressure and work.

Firstly, I would like to remind you that every job has its own dignity. If you want to become a good programmer then you could had taken programming as a passion, Likewise If you want to become a good tester then this job also needs to be taken as a passion first.

**"You should love your job then only you can be on top."**

In your case what happens is that if you are really interested to become a tester and quite interested in providing quality for everything which goes through your hand then for sure you can be a good tester.

Actually quality is inversely proportional to the risk of tester. If the quality goes up risk is low, but quality is low risk is extremely high. So you can't say if you work as a tester then you can live a peaceful life.

**TESTER -- TEST** **E**verything **R**ight. This what i believe in my concept.

You cant say you will find bugs within 10 minutes and can sit idle for rest of time. No, Its not possible.

While transferring from development to QA environment what happen is the lack of process knowledge. Testing also contain several methods which are used according to the environment and time constraints. These methods can be familiarized by reading through several tutorials 
For Example:
1)http://www.tutorialspoint.com
2)http://www.guru99.com

Since you had worked in programming for several years you could had gone through several loopholes in building complex logic's into easy ones. So, I better do say towards you to stay and become an automation tester with better knowledge in manual testing process.