# How to gain the required initial experience in software testing?

Tags: automated-testing, istqb

Although I can see many routes to get an education in testing, programming, etc. how can I address the requirement that nearly all jobs seem to require some actual software testing experience as well ?

What should one do to gain experience in software testing ?

Any tips for what should be on your resume for a candidate who is applying for jobs in QA automation ? Apart from the ISTQB Foundation Certification.

Comment: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/5156/what-options-are-available-in-the-career-path-of-a-tester/5158#5158, https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/8349/changing-my-career-field-to-qa

Comment: Gain experience in using google to find answers

Comment: Get help from the community to make better questions that are answerable.  Done.  Improve the format of answers from folks trying to also encourage them as new users in our community.  Done.  Translate for others.. Done.

Comment: @Tabish: What is your level of education? Programming skills, if any? other relevant skills in the area you will be testing?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I think you should start to find out about test automation, such as Selemiun Web Driver + VIsual Studio, there are videos where super easy tests are generated, but then come, challenges like generating reports, taking pictures and then Test data from a database model.

It is what I am doing in my work. Or for example find out about these tools

- Serenity Framework
- Redwoodhq
- Robot framework
- Sahi Opena Source Automation Testing Tool For Web Applications
- Galen Framework
- Gauge Test Automation you'll actually like

Comment: Please answer in English

Comment: Ricardo, your answer is appreciated - really! But we need answers to be in English. I wish our site was big enough to need sister sites in other languages =)

Comment: Ricardo, please review the above English version as best you can

Answer (score 1):

I'm personally not sure about certifications (I don't have any), but in order to be considered as an experienced QA at most of the interviews, you should understand one thing - constant self education is the key to success.

- The QA role is the role where an employee knows his/her subject perfectly + a little bit from everywhere. Of course the base foundations: SDLC, TDLC, principles of Agile, different roles within the team.
- Get accounts in Udemy, Pluralsight, CodeSchool, CodeAcademy, etc. Those are free or very low cost accounts (usually no more than $30 per month), and are amazing value to help you be constantly learning, rather than paying couple thousands dollars for the class (plus travel, time, etc.) at local college.
- Attend local QA meetups (www.meetup.com), listen to the people, share your ideas, look what's trending on the market now.
- Watch linkedin news feed, what recruiters are looking for, requirements, what tools and etc.

Hopefully this clears the picture a little.

Comment: Added formatting

Comment: edX.org has FREE courses in programming, with additional $50 for certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Certifications are of no use if you cannot show that:

- you are competent programmer. Python is widely considered simplest for beginners (and has plenty of online resources), but you will need more. SQL, XML. likely it will take few years to become competent (but some companies might hire semi-competent for cheap).
- you can research problem you have and find a solution with help from Internet. Like find reviews of different tools, and make your own opinion, customized to your own circumstances.

Easiest way is to get hired as manual tester, and automate what you can, as you gain skills. This will require to spend lot of your personal time learning new skills - but if you will go pro, it will be your life anyway.